# JavaScript Image onload event binding

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have this piece of code that loops through an array and load images and notify when the images is loaded.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {                
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = url[i];
    imageObj.onload= (function(i){
                return function(){
                    console.log(i, 'loaded');
                }
            })(i);

}
```

It works fine. However if I try to do this it won't work:

```
imageObj.addEventListener('onload', function(
    console.log(i, 'loaded');
}, false);
```

What is the problem? And is there any way for me to avoid using closure in this case?

Comment: Not the only problem, but your second broken example is clearly broken JS, missing `i) {` at the end of the first line.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, shouldn't you first assign the event and then assign the src?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One part of the problem: The event is not called `onload`, but `load`.

```
imageObj.addEventListener('load', function() { /* ... */ }, false);
```

Other than that, since `i` changes outside of the event listener function, you need a closure.

Comment: @gillesc A normal ES5 array.forEach() will give you a new scope, so your bindings aren't always set on the last item. It will be less code than iterating through the indexes and adding your own closure too.