# validate on form submit for image dimension upto 150X50px with file API

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileapi

How to validate on form submit for image dimension upto `150X50px` with file API in jquery.?

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to File Reader from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader to read about how to do this. Here is code snippet from this page.

Use onLoad event handler on the image to get the height and width attributes to validate them. Here is an example [Javascript Image onload event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121797/javascript-image-onload-event-binding)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Image preview example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
  document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};

function loadImageFile() {
  if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }
  var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadImageFile();">
  <form name="uploadForm">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="Image preview" /></td>
          <td><input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile();" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```