# leaflet doesnt load url first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I have this code for loading a non geographical map inside a get function, to get the map i need everytime :

```
$scope.tableFloors = data;

//Creamos las dimensiones del mapa e inicializamos la url de la imagen correspondiente al plano
$scope.url = $scope.tableFloors.results[0].idBluePrint;
console.log("url: " + $scope.url);
//INICIALIZACIÓN DE VARIABLES NECESARIAS PARA GENERAR EL MAPA
//zoom mínimo para el mapa
$scope.minZoom = 1;
//zoom máximo para el mapa
$scope.maxZoom = 4;
//posición del centro para el mapa
$scope.center = [0, 0];
//zoom por defecto al cargar el mapa
$scope.zoom = 3;
//sistema de referencia de coordenadas
$scope.crs = L.CRS.Simple;
//atributo para mostrar/ocultar información extra
$scope.attributionControl = false;
$scope.map = L.map('image-map',
{
    minZoom: $scope.minZoom,
    maxZoom: $scope.maxZoom,
    center: $scope.center,
    zoom: $scope.zoom,
    crs: $scope.crs,
    attributionControl: $scope.attributionControl
});

//obtenemos el ancho y el alto de la foto del plano
$scope.fotoPlano = new Image();
$scope.fotoPlano.src = $scope.url;
$scope.width = $scope.fotoPlano.width;
$scope.height = $scope.fotoPlano.height;
// Calculamos los bordes de la imagen en el espacio de coordenadas
$scope.surOeste = $scope.map.unproject([0, $scope.height], $scope.map.getMaxZoom() - 1);
$scope.norEste = $scope.map.unproject([$scope.width, 0], $scope.map.getMaxZoom() - 1);;
$scope.bounds = new L.LatLngBounds($scope.surOeste, $scope.norEste);
// lo añadimos
L.imageOverlay($scope.url, $scope.bounds).addTo($scope.map).bringToFront();
$scope.myIcon = L.icon(
{
    iconUrl: 'assets/images/ic_location.png',
    // iconRetinaUrl: 'my-icon@2x.png',
    iconSize: [34, 34],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    // popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    // shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
    // shadowRetinaUrl: 'my-icon-shadow@2x.png',
    // shadowSize: [68, 95],
    // shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});

// establecemos los límites
$scope.map.setMaxBounds($scope.bounds);
$scope.yx = L.latLng;
$scope.xy = function (x, y)
{
    if (L.Util.isArray(x))
    { // When doing xy([x, y]);
        return $scope.yx(x[1], x[0]);
    }
    return $scope.yx(y, x); // When doing xy(x, y);
};

var puntoIncidencia1 = $scope.xy(100, -40);

var incidencia1 = L.marker(puntoIncidencia1,
{
    icon: $scope.myIcon,
    draggable: true
}).addTo($scope.map).bindPopup('incidencia1');
//version con mapclickevent
$scope.map.on('click',
    function mapClickListen(e)
    {
        var pos = e.latlng;
        console.log("pos: ", this.options);
        console.log('map click event');
        var marker = L.marker(
            pos,
            {
                draggable: true
            }
        );
        marker.on('drag', function (e)
        {
            console.log('marker drag event');
        });
        marker.on('dragstart', function (e)
        {
            console.log('marker dragstart event');
            $scope.map.off('click', mapClickListen);
        });
        marker.on('dragend', function (e)
        {
            console.log('marker dragend event');
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                $scope.map.on('click', mapClickListen);
            }, 10);
        });
        marker.addTo($scope.map);
    }
);
```

But the first time i call the function it doesnt load properly the image or if i delete cache the first time called doesnt load it too. It loads properly when i recall the function and after that if i dont delete cache it loads ok all the times, its only the first time it doesnt load properly... why?

Comment: well, i know what is the problem, the problem is the first time i call this:

$scope.fotoPlano = new Image();

$scope.fotoPlano.src = $scope.url;

$scope.width = $scope.fotoPlano.width;

$scope.height = $scope.fotoPlano.height;


the height and the width are 0
But i dont undertand the second time it takes well width and height.....
Any solution??

Comment: possible that the image doesn't get loaded by the time..when u refresh it works bcs the image has loaded...check the load event of the image, and when the image is loaded, then do what you want to do

Comment: i know the problem,  u were faster with the comment than me xd , its that width and height for the first time are 0 but i dont understand why or how can i fix this with an elegant/good solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121797/javascript-image-onload-event-binding

Comment: $scope.fotoPlano = new Image(); $scope.fotoPlano.addEventListener('load', function() { $scope.fotoPlano.src = $scope.url; $scope.width = $scope.fotoPlano.width; $scope.height = $scope.fotoPlano.height; console.log("ancho: " + $scope.width + " alto: " + $scope.height); }, false); So, if i understood u mean that but now it doesnt work, i put a console log into load function and it doesnt enter in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image doesn't get loaded by the time you are accessing its size.

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.addEventListener('load', function() { /* ... */ }, false); 
// use the load event to know that image has been loaded
```

Proceed when the image has been loaded.

Comment: //obtenemos el ancho y el alto de la foto del plano
            $scope.fotoPlano = new Image();
            $scope.fotoPlano.addEventListener('load', function() {
                $scope.fotoPlano.src = $scope.url;
                $scope.width = $scope.fotoPlano.width;
                $scope.height = $scope.fotoPlano.height;
                console.log("ancho: " + $scope.width + " alto: " + $scope.height);
            }, false);

So, if i understood u mean that but now it doesnt work, i put a console log into load function and it doesnt enter in

Comment: Can u please provide a jsbin